# PDO prepare is not replacing placeholders

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've used the following code in order to fill a database using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO :season
    VALUES
    (
        :tag,:rank, //and so on
    );              
");

for($l = 0; $l < count($data); $l++) {
    $stmt->execute([
        'season' => $tables[$i],
        'tag' => $data[$l]["tag"],
        'rank' => $data[$l]["rank"],
        // and so on
    ]);
}
```

But the response I get is:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )' at line 1' in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\CoC_API\legenden\SQL_Test\API_SQL.php

Does someone know where the error is?

Must I put every entry in quotes?

Comment: You aren't normally allowed to inject the table name as a parameter.

Comment: And additional to TiesonT. the parameter names in the execute()-call must be preceded with a leading colon.

Comment: Tieson's tip has fixed it. But is there any other way to make the table name dynamic. The table name is a numeric ID, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are bind values in wrong way. You have to use the name with `:` as in prepared query. You can see some examples in documentation of the `execute` method http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Replace this part of your code

```
for($l = 0; $l < count($data); $l++) {
    $stmt->execute([
        'season' => $tables[$i],
        'tag' => $data[$l]["tag"],
        'rank' => $data[$l]["rank"],
        // and so on
    ]);
}
```

with this

```
for($l = 0; $l < count($data); $l++) {
    $stmt->execute([
        ':season' => $tables[$i],
        ':tag' => $data[$l]["tag"],
        ':rank' => $data[$l]["rank"],
        // and so on
    ]);
}
```

You can also use a `bindValue` method like in this way

```
for($l = 0; $l < count($data); $l++) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':season', $tables[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':tag', $data[$l]["tag"]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':rank', $data[$l]["rank"]);
    //and so on
}

$stmt->execute();
```